# Using standard haskell generics libraries for typed type-isomorphisms

Tags: generics, haskell, ghc, haskell-platform

There are several generics libraries with numerous overlapping modules in just the Haskell Platform alone (`syb`, `Data.Typeable`, `Data.Data`, `GHC.Generics`), but I'm having trouble with a very basic generic programming task.

I want to be able to convert between types of the same shape, i.e. I want a polymorphic, typed conversion function between isomorphic types, essentially what is offered at the end of [this paper](http://igitur-archive.library.uu.nl/math/2007-0404-200310/jeuring_04_inferringtype.pdf)(PDF) where indexed type families are mentioned.

I'm not concerned with scrapping my boilerplate, but rather with being able to build new libraries around sum and product abstractions.

The question below is in terms of `GHC.Generic` which I thought was closest to what I needed, but other solutions are welcome.

---

The following two types have the same shape

```
data Pair = Pair Char Int deriving (Generic, Show)
data Pair2 = Pair2 Char Int deriving (Generic, Show)
```

I want to convert values between them using GHC.Generics. The following fails to typecheck because of all the phantom parameters and other nonsense:

```
f :: Pair -> Pair2
f = to . from
```

Ultimately I want a function akin to `fromInteger` that has a polymorphic return value for any `Generic` (or whatever other class could support this) instance. I guess I'm looking for something like `GHC.Generics`:

```
--class:
type family NormalForm a
class ToGeneric a where
    to :: a -> NormalForm a
class FromGeneric b where
    from :: NormalForm b -> b

--examples:
data A = A Char Int deriving Show
data B = B Char Int deriving Show

type instance NormalForm A = (Char,Int)
instance ToGeneric A where
    to (A a b) = (a,b)
instance FromGeneric A where
    from (a,b) = A a b

type instance NormalForm B = (Char,Int)
instance ToGeneric B where
    to (B a b) = (a,b)
instance FromGeneric B where
    from (a,b) = B a b

-- the function I'm looking for
coerce :: (ToGeneric a, FromGeneric b, NormalForm a ~ NormalForm b)=> a -> b
coerce = from . to
```

With the above we can do everything I want:

```
*Main> (coerce $A 'a' 1) :: B
B 'a' 1
*Main> (coerce $A 'a' 1) :: A
A 'a' 1
```

**EDIT:** This is how Nathan Howell's `f` function seems to work below, actually.

#### Questions

1. Is this possible to do with libraries currently in the haskell platform?
2. If not, could a library be defined that leveraged the existing `deriving` mechanism for `Generic`, `Data`, etc. without resorting to TH?

Comment: `Generic` uses various phantom types that make `Rep`s from different data types incompatible. The closest you are going to get to a real solution is using various type casts between the internals of `Generic`, but then you'd just as well be able to use [`unsafeCoerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Unsafe-Coerce.html#v:unsafeCoerce).

Comment: @dflemstr: thanks, I neglected to mention the phantom types as the culprit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If "of the same shape" means that datatypes are equal up to constructor names, record selectors and type synonyms then datatype conversion is as simple as traversing  representation.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances #-}

import GHC.Generics

conv
  :: (Generic a, Generic b, Conv (Rep a) (Rep b))
  => a -> b
conv = to . cv . from

class Conv a b where
  cv :: a x -> b x

-- skip irrelevant parts: datatype name, constructor name, selector
instance Conv f1 f2 => Conv (M1 i1 c1 f1) (M1 i2 c2 f2) where
  cv = M1 . cv . unM1

instance (Conv a1 a2, Conv b1 b2) => Conv (a1 :*: b1) (a2 :*: b2) where
  cv ~(a :*: b) = cv a :*: cv b

instance (Conv a1 a2, Conv b1 b2) => Conv (a1 :+: b1) (a2 :+: b2) where
  cv (L1 a) = L1 $ cv a
  cv (R1 b) = R1 $ cv b

-- copy values
instance Conv U1 U1 where cv = id
instance Conv (K1 R c) (K1 R c) where cv = id
```

Test case:

```
data A = A1 String Int | A2 (Int,Int) deriving (Generic, Show)
data B = B1 [Char] Int | B2 { xy :: (Int,Int) } deriving (Generic, Show)
data X = X Int Int deriving (Generic, Show)

*Main> conv $ X 3 14 :: (Int,Int)
(3,14)
*Main> conv $ A1 "hello" 42 :: B
B1 "hello" 42
*Main> conv $ A2 (13,42) :: B
B2 {xy = (13,42)}
```

### Update

A few more instances allow more interesting conversions:

```
instance Conv U1 (M1 S s (K1 R ())) where
  cv _ = M1 $ K1 ()
-- *> conv (Nothing :: Maybe Int) :: Either () Int
-- Left ()

instance Conv (M1 S s (K1 R ())) U1 where
  cv _ = U1
-- *> conv (Left () :: Either () Int) :: Maybe Int
-- Nothing

-- this one requires OverlappingInstances
instance (Generic c1, Generic c2, Conv (Rep c1) (Rep c2))
  => Conv (K1 R c1) (K1 R c2)
  where
    cv (K1 x) = K1 $ conv x
 -- *> conv (Right Nothing :: Either () (Maybe Int)) :: Maybe (Either () Int)
 -- Just (Left ())

 -- data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a) deriving (Generic, Show)
 -- *> conv [1,2,3::Int] :: List Int
 -- Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Empty))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this closer in a bit, but I had another requests: support recursive types, i.e. consider `[a]` same shape as `Cons a (List a) | Empty`

Answer (score 9):

It is possible, and relatively painless. Unlike using `unsafeCoerce` directly, you'll get a build break if the types don't line up. You can probably rely on the equality constraints on `f` to provide enough compile time type safety to use `unsafeCoerce` and avoid working with the `Rep` family.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Generics

data Pair1 = Pair1 Char Int deriving (Generic, Show)
data Pair2 = Pair2 Char Int deriving (Generic, Show)

data Triple1 = Triple1 Char Int Double deriving (Generic, Show)
data Triple2 = Triple2 Char Int Double deriving (Generic, Show)

f :: (Generic a, Generic c, Rep a ~ D1 da (C1 ca f), Rep c ~ D1 db (C1 cb f))
  => a -> c
f = to . M1 . M1 . unM1 . unM1 . from
-- this might also be acceptable:
-- f = unsafeCoerce

p1 :: Pair1 -> Pair2
p1 = f

p2 :: Pair2 -> Pair1
p2 = f

t1 :: Triple1 -> Triple2
t1 = f

t2 :: Triple2 -> Triple1
t2 = f
```

Running it yields the expected result:

```
*Main> p1 $ Pair1 'x' 1
Pair2 'x' 1
*Main> p2 $ Pair2 'x' 1
Pair1 'x' 1
*Main> t1 $ Triple1 'y' 2 3.0
Triple2 'y' 2 3.0
*Main> t2 $ Triple2 'y' 2 3.0
Triple1 'y' 2 3.0
```

Comment: I think that the point was that it should work for any pair of types `Pair` and `Pair2` with the same shape; otherwise you could have just done `f (Pair a b) = Pair2 a b`.

Comment: @dflemstr Fair enough. I updated the code to work for more types.

Comment: Very nice. I did not know that this was possible; I thought that the result type would not be able to be induced when the constraints are so disjoint as to only be linked by the field structure, but I guess it works if you provide explicit type signatures for every specialization of `f`.

Comment: @NathanHowell Okay, I'm waffling on whether I want to accept this answer. Can you get it to work with types with multiple constructors? I've also broadened the scope of the question to include any of the generics stuff in the haskell platform if you want to submit another answer with a different approach. Sorry to be difficult!

Comment: @jberryman, can you provide some details on when two types with multiple constructors are of the same shape? Е.g. `data A = A1 Char | A2 Int` and `data B = B1 Int | B2 Char`? And what about `data C = C1 Int | C2 Int | C3 Char`?

Comment: @maxtaldykin yeah, the fact that the ordering of constructors for sum types becomes significant (where it isn't in normal code; when you're pattern matching, say) is a bit awkward. For my purposes I am content with treating all of your examples as unequal.