# Type Families with GHC.Generics or Data.Data

Tags: generics, haskell, ghc, type-families

*This is a question related to my module [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/simple-actors/0.4.0/doc/html/Control-Concurrent-Actors.html), and is simplified a bit. It's also related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11887666/176841) previous question, in which I oversimplified my problem and didn't get the answer I was looking for. I hope this isn't too specific, and please change the title if you can think if a better one.*

### Background

My module uses a concurrent chan, split into a read side and write side. I use a special class with an associated type synonym to support polymorphic channel "joins":

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Sources s where
    type Joined s
    newJoinedChan :: IO (s, Messages (Joined s)) -- NOT EXPORTED

--output and input sides of channel:
data Messages a  -- NOT EXPORTED
data Mailbox a

instance Sources (Mailbox a) where
    type Joined (Mailbox a) = a
    newJoinedChan = undefined

instance (Sources a, Sources b)=> Sources (a,b) where
    type Joined (a,b) = (Joined a, Joined b)
    newJoinedChan = undefined

-- and so on for tuples of 3,4,5...
```

The code above allows us to do this kind of thing:

```
example = do
    (mb ,        msgsA) <- newJoinedChan
    ((mb1, mb2), msgsB) <- newJoinedChan
    --say that: msgsA, msgsB :: Messages (Int,Int)
    --and:      mb :: Mailbox (Int,Int)
    --          mb1,mb2 :: Mailbox Int
```

We have a recursive action called a `Behavior` that we can run on the messages we pull out of the "read" end of the channel:

```
newtype Behavior a = Behavior (a -> IO (Behavior a))
runBehaviorOn :: Behavior a -> Messages a -> IO ()  -- NOT EXPORTED
```

This would allow us to run a `Behavior (Int,Int)` on either of `msgsA` or `msgsB`, where in the second case both `Int`s in the tuple it receives actually came through separate `Mailbox`es.

This is all tied together for the user in the exposed `spawn` function

```
spawn :: (Sources s) => Behavior (Joined s) -> IO s
```

...which calls `newJoinedChan` and `runBehaviorOn`, and returns the input `Sources`.

### What I'd like to do

I'd like users to be able to create a `Behavior` of arbitrary product type (not just tuples) , so for instance we could run a `Behavior (Pair Int Int)` on the example `Messages` above. I'd like to do this with `GHC.Generics` while still having a polymorphic `Sources`, but can't manage to make it work.

```
spawn :: (Sources s, Generic (Joined s), Rep (Joined s) ~ ??) => Behavior (Joined s) -> IO s
```

The parts of the above example that are actually exposed in the API are the `fst` of the `newJoinedChan` action, and `Behavior`s, so an acceptable solution can modify one or all of `runBehaviorOn` or the `snd` of `newJoinedChan`.

I'll also be extending the API above to support sums (not implemented yet) like `Behavior (Either a b)` so I hoped GHC.Generics would work for me.

### Questions

1. Is there a way I can extend the API above to support arbitrary `Generic a=> Behavior a`?
2. If not using GHC's Generics, are there other ways I can get the API I want with minimal end-user pain (i.e. they just have to add a deriving clause to their type)? e.g. with `Data.Data`?

Comment: It's possible to do this with `GHC.Generics`. I might have time later in the week to code up an example if nobody else gets around to it first.

Comment: @NathanHowell added a little bounty if you have time to figure out a solution

Comment: @NathanHowell: weeeeell? :)

Comment: Been busy sorry, I'll see what I can do but can't work on it today.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen leave the man alone ;)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DeriveGeneric, DefaultSignatures, TypeOperators, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, UndecidableInstances #-}

import Control.Arrow
import GHC.Generics

class Sources s where
    type Joined s
    newJoinedChan :: IO (s, Messages (Joined s)) -- NOT EXPORTED
    default newJoinedChan :: (Generic s, SourcesG (Rep s)) => IO (s, Messages (JoinedG (Rep s)))
    newJoinedChan = fmap (first to) newJoinedChanG

class SourcesG g where
    type JoinedG g
    newJoinedChanG :: IO (g a, Messages (JoinedG g))

--output and input sides of channel:
data Messages a  -- NOT EXPORTED
data Mailbox a

instance Sources (Mailbox a) where
    type Joined (Mailbox a) = a
    newJoinedChan = undefined

instance (Sources a, Sources b)=> Sources (a,b) where
    type Joined (a,b) = (Joined a, Joined b)
    newJoinedChan = undefined

instance (SourcesG a, SourcesG b) => SourcesG (a :*: b) where
    type JoinedG (a :*: b) = (JoinedG a, JoinedG b)
    newJoinedChanG = undefined

instance (SourcesG a, Datatype c) => SourcesG (M1 D c a) where
    type JoinedG (M1 D c a) = JoinedG a
    newJoinedChanG = fmap (first M1) newJoinedChanG

instance (SourcesG a, Constructor c) => SourcesG (M1 C c a) where
    type JoinedG (M1 C c a) = JoinedG a
    newJoinedChanG = fmap (first M1) newJoinedChanG

instance (SourcesG a, Selector c) => SourcesG (M1 S c a) where
    type JoinedG (M1 S c a) = JoinedG a
    newJoinedChanG = fmap (first M1) newJoinedChanG

instance Sources s => SourcesG (K1 i s) where
    type JoinedG (K1 i s) = Joined s
    newJoinedChanG = fmap (first K1) newJoinedChan

newtype Behavior a = Behavior (a -> IO (Behavior a))

runBehaviorOn :: Behavior a -> Messages a -> IO ()
runBehaviorOn = undefined

spawn :: (Sources s) => Behavior (Joined s) -> IO s
spawn = undefined

data Pair a b = Pair a b deriving (Generic)

instance (Sources a, Sources b) => Sources (Pair a b) where
    type Joined (Pair a b) = JoinedG (Rep (Pair a b))
```