# DRYer Generic types in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, types, dry, dto

Say I have the following types:

```
newtype AddressID = {unAddressId :: UUID } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
newtype PersonID = {unPersonId :: UUID } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
data Address = { addressId :: AddressID} deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
data Person  = { personId :: PersonID } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)
data AddressDto = AddressDto { addressDtoId :: !UUID } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)

data PersonDto = PersonDto { personDtoId :: !UUID } deriving (Generic, Show, Eq)

type AddressListDto = HashMap UUID AddressDto

type PersonListDto = HashMap UUID PersonDto

instance FromJSON PersonDto where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON $ apiOptions "personDto"

instance ToJSON PersonDto where
  toJSON     = genericToJSON $ apiOptions "personDto"
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding $ apiOptions "personDto"

instance FromJSON AddressDto where
  parseJSON = genericParseJSON $ apiOptions "addressDto"

instance ToJSON AddressDto where
  toJSON     = genericToJSON $ apiOptions "addressDto"
  toEncoding = genericToEncoding $ apiOptions "addressDto"
```

with the following utility functions:

```
fromAddress :: Address -> AddressDto
fromAddress Address{..} = AddressDto {addresDtoId = unAddressId addressId}

fromPerson :: Person -> PersonDto
fromAddress Person{..} = PersonDto {personDtoId = unPersonId personId}

appendPerson :: PersonListDto -> Person -> PersonListDto
appendPerson pld per = insert (personDtoId $ fromPerson per) (fromPolicy per) pld


fromPersonList :: [Person] -> PersonListDto
fromPersonList = foldl appendPerson empty


appendAddress :: AddressListDto -> Address -> AddressListDto
appendAddress ald addr = insert (addressDtoId $ fromAddress addr) (fromAddress addr) ald


fromAddressList :: [Address] -> AddressListDto
fromAddressList = foldl appendAddress empty
```

This code works just fine, however it is very repeated, and balloons with the number of these internal types. The functions are identical, but operate across different objects, with a naming convention on helper functions being the only thing separating the different implementations.

What is the Haskell approach to creating more generically reusable helper functions across these types? How do I go about creating a `fromEntity`, `fromDto`, `appendEntityToDtoList` and `fromEntityList` functions? Is there a way I can encode (the virtually identical) To/FromJSON instances without repeating myself? Are Typeclasses appropriate here? Is there some good material on how to use them for this purpose?

Comment: you can scrap most of your boilerplate with generics. you can start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887666/using-standard-haskell-generics-libraries-for-typed-type-isomorphisms

Comment: Have you considered taking your problem to Code Review?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard, I don't think this question would be the best match for that site. Could be wrong, but "I don't like my approach to the problem; how can I find a new one?" seems more like a question for here.

Comment: What is `apiOptions`?

Answer (score 1):

For the JSON instances, yes, you can definitely reduce the boilerplate, at the cost of some setup. The biggest trick is a relatively new GHC feature, `DerivingVia`. This lets you explain how to create an instance for one type in terms of the instance for another.

```
{-# language DeriveGeneric, DerivingVia, StandaloneDeriving
 , TypeFamilies, UndecidableInstances, ScopedTypeVariables
 , PolyKinds, TypeApplications #-}

-- A newtype wrapper for the type we want an instance for
newtype Optionish a = Optionish a

-- A FromJSON instance for Optionish
instance
  ( Generic a
  , Rep a ~ M1 i c f
  , Datatype c
  , GFromJSON Zero f
  )
  => FromJSON (Optionish a) where
  parseJSON v = Optionish <$> genericParseJSON (apiOptions (lower name)) v
    where
      name = datatypeName (Proxy3 @c)

data Proxy3 d f a = Proxy3

lower :: String -> String
lower "" = ""
lower (x:xs) = toLower x : xs
```

We can use this like so:

```
deriving via Optionish PersonDto
  instance FromJSON PersonDto
```

You can do just the same sort of thing for `ToJSON`.

Comment: There's also a package https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-aeson

Comment: @Li-yaoXia, why don't you write an answer showing how to do it with that?

Comment: I think the mention is enough for interested readers to figure out. And if I just put the link in an answer, someone is going to tell me to make it more substantial...